# Caulk/paint between wall and ceiling falling off, how to paint over?

Tags: painting, caulking

We just removed wallpaper from one wall in our new house. Most of the wall underneath just looks like plastered concrete wall, however, close to the ceiling, it looks like there is instead white paint

[image: 2]

since it is much whiter than the rest of the wall, although there is not a clear transition between the whiter part and the rest which is a bit strange. This paint is coming off close to the ceiling. Moreover, between the wall and the ceiling there seems to be a layer of caulk (or something similar), which is falling off in some places

[image: 1]

We are very puzzled why close to the ceiling, the wall is white, but the rest of the wall looks like just plastered concrete, and not sure how to deal with this. Should we try to scrape off all the white paint? Or should we just prime and paint over it? Should we also remove all the caulk(?) between the ceiling and wall and then recaulk? Or just recaulk the parts that have fallen off? Or can we just use a joint filler? Or ignore it completely? We don't plan to paint the wall white, so maybe that is also a relevant factor.

EDIT: After further inspection, it actually looks like it is not painted, it is just the caulk that has been smeared out on a very large surface close to the ceiling...

Comment: Before painting, prep is _vital_! Your paint may stick to whatever is there, but if that whatever is falling off, it will take the paint with it when it goes. Scrape off any loose stuff before you spend time and money applying paint.

Comment: Yes that is what we want to do. However we are unsure how to prep here because it looks like the caulk (or whatever) that is normally only put in the corner has been smeared over a very large surface on the wall, and is very hard to remove. Sure we can scrape off the loose stuff, but will that be enough? Or do we have to remove everything?

Comment: _Generally_ speaking caulk is paintable. There are those specifically marked as "paintable", but most will hold paint, for those that you don't know about.